# Delete an user object automatically after some time in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I want automatically delete the user object or make default="" in my model after 2 min.
Here is my model. What am I doing wrong!!

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import date


class Action(models.TextChoices):
    REQUESTED = 'Requested'
    ACCEPTED = 'Accepted'
    REJECTED = 'Rejected'

class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')
    membership_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    membership_action = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Action.choices, default=Action.REQUESTED)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,blank=True,)

    @property
    def delete_after_thirty_days(self):
        time = self.start_date + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
    
        if time < datetime.datetime.now():
            e = UserMembership.objects.get(user=self.user)
            e.delete()
            return True
        else:
            return False



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Basically, after 2 minutes the values of the UserMembership model related to the specific user should be deleted or change back to default values. currently, nothing happens and I don't get any errors as well. Thank you for your time.

Comment: where have you called **delete_after_thirty_days** property ???

Comment: okay, so that's the problem ?? I actually don't know where to call it !! I am new to web applications can you suggest to me something.

Comment: django celery might help you --> https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html